# Raspberry pi zero not booting

Tags: boot, boot-issues, pi-zero

I just got a brand new raspberry pi zero and it won't boot. I have an "old" raspberry pi zero and it boots fine with my sd cards/ power supplies.

I even connected my bare pi zeros with usb to my windows machine and my old zero shows BCM2708 Boot and my new pi zero doesn't show this.

Does anyone know if my new pi zero is dead?

Comment: Welcome! When you say "old" and "new", do you mean just different in time of your ownership, or do you mean "old" as without the CSI interface and "new" as in with that interface on the Pi Zero board?

Comment: Thanks! With old I mean my pi zero which I got six months ago. And with new I mean my pi zero which I got today.

Comment: Does either Pi Zero have a CSI camera connector? i.e. Do they *look* different physically?

Comment: Yes they look 1:1 the same. They're both version 1.3

Comment: Does the led show any activity when you try to boot it? Can you record a video with your smartphone?

Comment: No the led doesn't do anything. When I plug the cable in, it does nothing. No led, no Video ouput, nothing.

Comment: Welcome to  the Stack Exchange Network - and the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of it.  I hate to say it but it does sound as though your "new" Pi Zero may be in such a state that you can have the __[tag:rip]__ tag for this Question. 8-( As far I recall there is not any modifiable "state" information stored on the hardware when it is switched off - so if two units which are identical and have the same hardware (including the SD card) connected but one doesn't go then it is faulty - IMHO.  Return it to supplier for a replacement/refund!

Comment: Agreed.  Sounds like a dead zero to me (and given the supply constraints, that makes me immeasurably sad).  I killed a zero recently thanks to, er, over soldering, and I was super glad I had a spare :-/

Answer (score 2):

Before sending it back, I would opt for a new or formatted SD card with fresh and up-to-date jessie on it. If you don't want to waste time use Raspbian Jessie Lite it copies faster to SD card. If this doesn't boot, the pi zero is probably in brick state.